SQL table Alias
I have the following SQL statement where the Company table is joined 3 times.  There is a CompanyName column in the Company table  How do I tell my c# code which alias to read?
reader["ex.CompanyName"] does not work
Select *
from Shipments sh
inner join Company cn on cn.CompanyId = sh.ConsigneeID
inner join Company ex on ex.CompanyId = sh.ExporterId
inner join Company fw on fw.CompanyID = sh.ForwarderID


Rename the columns in the SELECT list, e.g. SELECT ex.CompanyName as ex_CompanyName, ...

You can't. Alias the columns so that they are distinct, or access them by index in your DataReader.

You should generally write table_name.column_name or table_alias.column_name and never use *

Why don't you replace SELECT * with SELECT sh.col1, cn.col1, ...?

Select
    cn.CompanyName as CompanyNameCN,
    ex.CompanyName as CompanyNameEX,
    fw.CompanyName as CompanyNameFW
from Shipments sh
inner join Company cn on cn.CompanyId = sh.ConsigneeID
inner join Company ex on ex.CompanyId = sh.ExporterId
inner join Company fw on fw.CompanyID = sh.ForwarderID

use reader["CompanyNameCN"], reader["CompanyNameEX"], reader["CompanyNameFW"]

To handle this in your C# code, you need to alias the CompanyName column in your SQL query so that each instance has a unique name. This way, you can reference the specific alias in your SqlDataReader.
In SQL -
SELECT 
    sh.*, 
    cn.CompanyName AS ConsigneeName, 
    ex.CompanyName AS ExporterName, 
    fw.CompanyName AS ForwarderName
FROM 
    Shipments sh
INNER JOIN 
    Company cn ON cn.CompanyId = sh.ConsigneeID
INNER JOIN 
    Company ex ON ex.CompanyId = sh.ExporterId
INNER JOIN 
    Company fw ON fw.CompanyID = sh.ForwarderID

In C# -
var consigneeName = reader["ConsigneeName"].ToString();
var exporterName = reader["ExporterName"].ToString();
var forwarderName = reader["ForwarderName"].ToString();


Option 1: alias the columns:
Select ex.CompanyName as [FromCompanyName], cn.CompanyName as [ToCompanyName]
from Shipments sh
inner join Company cn on cn.CompanyId = sh.ConsigneeID
inner join Company ex on ex.CompanyId = sh.ExporterId
inner join Company fw on fw.CompanyID = sh.ForwarderID

Option 2: find the ordinals (indices) of the columns you want, by looping over the fields to find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc mention of "CompanyName", using reader.GetName() while looping from 0 to reader.FieldCount - 1, using the ordinal-based Get* methods to read the data.
Option 3: use a tool like Dapper, with the splitOn parameter; if we assume that Company has CompanyId as the first column, then something like:
var data = conn.Query<Company, Company, Company, Company,
    (Company sh, Company cn, Company ex, Company fw)>(
    sql, (sh, cn, ex, fw) => (sh, cn, ex, fw), splitOn: "CompanyId").AsList();

Side note: select * is almost always a bad idea in general; I'd advocate for at least making the order obvious, i.e. select sh.*, cn.*, ex.*, fw.*, but personally I'd be explicit about every column. If you only want the names, then it gets much easier:
select sh.CompanyName, cn.CompanyName, ex.CompanyName, fw.CompanyName

and either GetString(0) thru GetString(3), or with Dapper:
var data = conn.Query<(string sh, string cn, string ex, string fw)>(sql).AsList();

